# Displayport to HDMI Converter Issue: Second Monitor No Signal after BIOS on AMD Ryzen 5 4600G Dual Monitor Setup

Tags: 22.04, hdmi, amd-graphics, bios, displayport

I have a dual monitor setup with an AMD Ryzen 5 4600G (Radeon Graphics) CPU. My motherboard has one DisplayPort and one HDMI port. I connected Monitor 1 to the HDMI port and Monitor 2 to the DisplayPort using a DisplayPort to HDMI converter, as Monitor 2 has both HDMI and DP ports.

During the boot process, both monitors display the motherboard logo and BIOS screen correctly. However, after Ubuntu (22.04) loads, only Monitor 1 is working, and Monitor 2 shows 'No Signal.' Strangely, when I connect Monitor 2 directly using a DP cable (without the converter), both monitors work without any issue.

What could be causing the DisplayPort to HDMI converter to stop working after the BIOS screen? Is there a specific BIOS or driver setting that might resolve this issue? Any insights or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

xrandr output with HDMI to DP converter

```
xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-A-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 543mm x 302mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+ 100.00    84.90    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
HDMI-A-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

xrandr output without HDMI to DP converter

```
xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-A-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 543mm x 302mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+ 100.00    84.90    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
HDMI-A-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-0 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 530mm x 290mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+ 100.00    85.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00    50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Comment: What is the model and type of the converter?

Comment: Unfortunately It is an unbranded one. https://www.flipkart.com/eira-tv-out-cable-displayport-dp-hdmi-adapter-4k-male-female-converter-connector-display-port-enabled-desktops-laptops-connect-displays/p/itm665198a15cff8

Comment: Do `lspci` or `lsusb` or `sudo lshw` provide any useful output?

Comment: couldn't find useful info, I Updated question with xrandr -q
 outputs

Comment: Can HDCP cause this issue ?